# I need help for my Regex in C#

Tags: c#, html, css, regex

I'm trying to find a CSS URL using a regex but having no experience with it, and I'm lost.

After research , I've made this:

```
^(href)([\S]*(\.css))(\")$
```

but it works only with

```
href="/media/system/css/modal.css"
```

and I've got to find it in:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/system/css/modal.css" type="text/css" />
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.campingbellavista.ch/compon [...] k2/css/k2.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: If you specify ^ and $ you are stating that the pattern has to starts form the beginning of the line and ends at the end of the line. Try to remove ^ and $ from you regex. And consider to check at the reply of this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags. Being french should not affect how Regex works ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe simplify? ]*href="([^"]+)"

An awesome place to screw around with your regexes I've found was http://www.rubular.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a parser like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and some XPath:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422517");
var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//link[@rel='stylesheet']");
foreach (var node in links)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["href"].Value);
}
```

Or, to select all elements with `href` that ends with `.css`:

```
var links = doc.DocumentNode.DescendantNodesAndSelf()
               .Where(node => node.Attributes.Contains("href") && 
                              node.Attributes["href"].Value.EndsWith(".css"));
```

Comment: Couldn't get that second xpath to work on HAP, to be honest. Should be something like `//link[ends-with(@href,'css')]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your Pattern

```
^(href)([\S]*(\.css))(\")$
```

`^` means match the start of the string ==> NOT true in your second example

`$` means match the end of the string ==> NOT true in your second example

You can just delete thos anchors from your pattern and it should match the second example.

You have a lot of unnecessary brackets in your expression. This is doing the same

```
href\S*\.css\"
```

The `()` brackets have the meaning that they group the content and put the matched pattern into a capturing group. I assume you don't want this, at least not the way you used them.

probably you want something like this

```
href=\"(\S*\.css)\"
```

so the hyperlink is in the capturing group 1.

The `[]` creates a character class, but thats not needed if you put only one item into it. So `[\S]` is the same than `\S`.

But at last I would suggest, that you have a closer look at Kobi's answer.

Answer (score 0):

how about this: href="([^"]*)"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
href="([^"]*?\.css)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Regex expression = new Regex("<.*href=\"(?<CSSUrl>.*css)\".*", RegexOptions.None);
```

With that you can get the URL with the groupname "CSSUrl".